# Function call as an expression for set comprehension

Tags: python

What is the difference between these two calls?
How does the second example syntax works ? how valid is using colon : in second example ?

```
   with concurrent.futures.Executor() as executor:
      futures = {executor.submit(perform, task) for task in get_tasks()}
```

and

```
 with concurrent.futures.Executor() as executor:
    futures = {executor.submit(perform, task): task for task in get_tasks()}
```

Would you give me some more example regarding using colon in set comprehension ?
regards

Answer (score 2):

The first example is a `set` comprehension, the second is a `dictionary` comprehension.

```
numbers = [1, 2, 2]
set_comp = {n for n in numbers}
dict_comp = {index: value for index, value in enumerate(numbers)}

print(set_comp, dict_comp)
```

Output:

```
{1, 2}
{0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 2}
```